# Cartthrob - Quick View/Quick Buy

Tags: cartthrob

I'm needing to add a Quick View/Quick Buy feature to my client's products page. Basically when they click the Quick Buy button a modal/div containing product details and a Buy button should display. My client would rather have this than a separate product details page. Is there a recommended way to do this? I was thinking that I could pass the product id as a parameter in the call to open up the modal and have the product details functionality hidden in the modal div.

I've added the code below.

```
    <!-- product with call to modal -->
    {exp:channel:entries channel="assets" dynamic="no" sort="asc" category="22" limit="1" entry_id="23"}
 <ul>
      <li><strong>Date:</strong> {asset_date}</li>
      <li><strong>Price:</strong> {product_price}</li>
      <li><strong>Status: <span style="color: #5cb85c">Available</span></strong></li>
      <li class="reserve-button"><a data-toggle="modal" href="#styledModal" data-id="{entry_id}" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Reserve Asset</a></li>
  </ul>
  {/exp:channel:entries}

    <!-- product details modal content -->
    {exp:channel:entries channel="assets" category_id="22" limit="1"}
      {exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form id="add-cart" entry_id="{entry_id}" no_tax="{no_tax}" no_shipping = "{no_shipping}" return="checkout/view_cart"} 
        <ul>
          <li><strong>Date:</strong> {asset_date}</li>
          <li><strong>Price:</strong> {product_price}</li>
          <li><strong>Status: <span style="color: #5cb85c">Available</span></strong></li>
          <li class="reserve-button"><button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Reserve Asset</button></li>
        </ul>
      {/exp:cartthrob:add_to_cart_form} 
     {/exp:channel:entries}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I may be misunderstanding, but whether your div is modal or not isn't a any kind of deal really - you'd just have (another) add_to_cart form in it along with any details you need.

Comment: Thank you, Jeremy. Thank you for your reply. That's kind of what I was thinking but i'm having issues passing the entry_id for some reason. Works fine if I use entry_id_path and want to go to a details page. But the modal is not picking up the id. I've updated the initial entry with the code I've written to get this going. I left out the modal divs in the snippet above just to make it cleaner. If you have time to look it over, that would be great. I appreciate your time.

Comment: Hurjas - I think your basic issue is more structural - why do you need two channel entries loops (with different paramaters!) - I would wrap the whole thing in one channel entries loop.  I am going to guess your issue is your second channel entries look does not have dynamic="no" or an entry_id etc...  (Of course even better might be to use stash to set all the data for alter retrieval but that's beyond the scope of this question!).

Comment: Jeremy, thank you. You were spot on. I was overthinking it a bit. Cleaned up the multiple channel entries and wrapped everything in one channel entries loop and the 'quick buy' is working as intended. I was looking at Stash before you made the recommendation. I will work on that next. Again, thank you.

Comment: No worries. With EE its often the way - stepping back and looking at the bigger picture can really help.  Stash is a huge leap forward for EE dev once you work it out. Good luck!

Comment: @hurjas how did you set this up? Could you provide me with the code?